# How to compare the elements of an ArrayList with every element of another ArrayList using Stream API of Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have two Sorted ArrayList of same size, namely `team_A` & `team_B`, in which comparing every element of `team_A` with `team_B` to find the `powerDiff > 0`. After finding the `powerDiff` greater than 0, then removing that element from the `team_B` to reduce the number of iteration in the next cycle.

```
long calculateWin(){
    int wins = 0;
    int tempIndex=0;
    boolean flag = false;
    long powerDiff=0;

    for(int i=0; i<team_A.size(); i++) {

        for(int j=0; j<team_B.size(); j++) {

            powerDiff = team_A.get(i) - team_B.get(j);

            if(powerDiff>0) {
                wins++;
                tempIndex=j;
                flag=true;
                break;
            }

        }

        if(flag) {
            team_B.remove(tempIndex);
            flag = false;
        }

    }
    return wins;

}
```

The above code is working fine but due to complexity I want to optimize this code using the Stream API of Java 8.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Not everything is better with streams.

Comment: Here in this problem I've to deal with max 1,00,000 long numbers, due to which the complexity is too high. So, is there any alternate or some suggestion to reduce the complexity.

Comment: Streams may look more streamline, but it does add more complexity at times.

Comment: In this example, use a enhanced for loop (`for (long a : team_A) {...}`) and an iterator for the second. It has a `.remove()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this one;

```
public static long calculateWinJava8(){
    List<Long> team_A = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(50L,60L,70L,80L,90L,100L));
    List<Long> team_B = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(30L,40L,25L,80L,55L,200L,250L));
    int wins = team_B.size();

    team_A.stream().forEach(itemA->{
         List<Long> removeItems = team_B.stream().filter(itemB-> (itemA-itemB)>0).collect(Collectors.toList());
         team_B.removeAll(removeItems);
    });

    System.out.println("result team_B : "+team_B.toString());
    wins = wins - team_B.size();
    System.out.println("wins : "+wins);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a good way with the standard JDK because it's lacking basic constructs like a .zip() operator and a Tuple class. If it did it would look something like this:

```
val wins = team_a.zip(team_b)
                .filter { tuple -> tuple.first > tuple.second }
                .count()
```

That's kotlin but there are a ton of java libaries that offer a .zip() and Tuple.

If you **really** want to do it with just the JDK it'd be something like:

```
long wins = IntStream
        .range(0, Math.min(team_a.size(), team_b.size()))
        .filter(i -> team_a.get(i) > team_b.get(i))
        .count();
```

This works but isn't ideal since you are reaching outside the pipeline unlike the first example.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's untangle the logic a bit.

You check for for each pair if a[i] > b[j]. And if it matches, you remove b[j].
Good. `long` has a total order, so, we only need it's maximum.

```
long max_a = team_a.stream().mapToLong(a -> a).max().getAsLong();
```

Now that we have the most powerful of team a, we check how many they can defeat:

```
long wins = team_b.stream().filter(b -> a > b).count();
```

And that's it.

---

Wait. I did not notice the key word "sorted" in your question.
This means we can do a binary search.

First we get the maximum. I assume the list are in ascending order.

```
long max_a = team_a.get(team_a.size()-1);
```

Now we need to find where we have to make the cut:

```
int idx = Collections.binarySearch(team_b, max_a);
```

Note that `Collections.binarySearch` can return a negative number if the maximum is not in the list. But we are only interested in the number of smaller items in the list.

```
if (idx < 0)
    idx = -idx - 1
```

Now `idx` contains the number of elements smaller than the largest element in the first list. Return that:

```
return idx;
```